# numpy.ndarray with zero dimensions and no shape still storing data

Tags: python, numpy, types

I am trying to compute a median of integers and return an integer in `numpy`. Here is what I think should work, according to the documentation of [numpy.median](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.median.html):

```
import numpy as np
m1 = np.median((1,2,3))
myout = np.zeros_like(m1, dtype=np.intp)
m2 = np.median((1,2,3), out=myout)
```

However, when typing `myout` and `m2` into my debugging console, the only value I get is `<ndarray>`. How do I get the value stored in there? Is there are? What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
What I have noticed from your comments is that `print(m2)` does print `2`, which is what I wanted. However, `m2` is still curious, since `m2.shape` is `()` and `m2.ndim` is `0`. This probably causes the debug console to not show the value of `2`. So I think my question now is, how can an `ndarray` have zero dimensions and still store data?

```
print(m2)
print(m2.shape)
print(m2.ndim)
```

Comment: Do you understand what would be - `np.median((1,2,3))`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why aren't you happy with `m1`? If you want to convert to int, simply use `int(m1)`

Comment: Typing it shows you the object which is indeed an array... Try calling `print(m2)` instead ?

Comment: @Divakar is this a test? I understand `np.median((1,2,3))` to be 2.0 stored as a `float64`.

Comment: @Julien I am learning a new language and trying out a multitude of different ways to do the same thing, to get a feel for it.

Comment: A 0-dim array has shape `()`, and one element, which should display in a print, and can pulled out with `.item()` method.

Comment: A 0-dim array is a scalar. `2` is not the same as `[2]`, nor `[[2]]` (even if they often behave the same way in computations).

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, this is really different from MATLAB. A zero-dimensional array does not even exist there, and a scalar (and a vector, for that matter) are implicitly two-dimensional objects.

Comment: The fact that MATLAB objects are always 2d (or above) complicates the transition to `numpy`, where 0d is possible, and 1d common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to replicate your bug, this works perfectly for me . Maybe some versioning issues? try using m2 and myout the way you want. Here's what I ran :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m1 = np.median((1,2,3))
>>> print (m1)
2.0
>>> myout = np.zeros_like(m1, dtype=np.intp)
>>> m2 = np.median((1,2,3), out=myout)
>>> print(myout)
2
>>> print(m2)
2
```

Comment: Not able to replicate either, but this is not worth an answer, a comment only or a flag...

Comment: Thanks, this is valuable. In fact, `print` does return 2. My question is (or should have been), why I am unable to inspect the value of `m2` in the debug console. I am using Visual Studio Code, if that matters.

Comment: Did you add the python extension for VSCode ?

Comment: @npf, the questioner does think this answers the question. It isn't helpful to overly picky about the distinction between comment and a answer..